# Add New Row in GridView winform on Button Click

Tags: c#-4.0

Add New Row in GridView winform on Button Click.
Need to have single button in grid rather than DataGridViewButtonColumn

Comment: Where to Put Button.. Can i Put it on Grip of Last Row of DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add it by using

GridView1.DataSource = datatable;

and then add new row by this

datatable.Rows.Add();

this will add new row and give control id into add().

Comment: use this 
DataGridViewButtonColumn deleteButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

deleteButton.HeaderText = "Delete";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(deleteButton);

Comment: But i want to use only single Button... not Button Column

Answer (score 1):

```
use this 

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button textBoxDgv1 = new Button();
        Label labelDgv1 = new Label();
the next is on the Form_Load event

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelDgv1.Text = "Delete";
            labelDgv1.Height = 20;
            labelDgv1.AutoSize = false;
            labelDgv1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            labelDgv1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            int Xdgv1 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(2, -1, true).Location.X;
            labelDgv1.Width = this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width + Xdgv1;
            labelDgv1.Location = new Point(0, this.dataGridView1.Height - textBoxDgv1.Height);
            this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(labelDgv1);

and one more section is in dataGridView1_CellPainting

private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
       int sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != string.Empty)
           {
               sum += Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1[3, i].Value);
           }
       }
           textBoxDgv1.Text = sum.ToString();
           int Xdgvx = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(2, -1, true).Location.X;
           labelDgv1.Width = this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width + Xdgvx;
           labelDgv1.Location = new Point(0, this.dataGridView1.Height - textBoxDgv1.Height);
           textBoxDgv1.Width = this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width;
           Xdgvx = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(3, -1, true).Location.X;
           textBoxDgv1.Location = new Point(Xdgvx, this.dataGridView1.Height - textBoxDgv1.Height);
}
```

Comment: Vote this Answer if you are satisfied with this.